# Construction of Pythagorean triples

Tags: pythagorean-triples

If $(x,y,z)$ is a Pythagorean triple, then $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ is again a Pythagorean triple. This is easy to show. But **how** can one come up with this matrix?

Comment: Use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) for generating all Pythagorean triples and choose the matrix accordingly. Everything is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) with $3\times 3$ matrices, section "Pythagorean triples by use of matrices and linear transformations". If you prefer a link to a duplicate on MSE, then look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965206/how-to-descend-within-the-tree-of-primitive-pythagorean-triples), and the references given there.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but that does not answer the question **how** one can come up with this matrix

Comment: It does. Just rewrite the triple-generating formula as matrix multiplication, see the wikipedia section "Pythagorean triples by use of matrices and linear transformations". How to find the formula, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395543/formulas-for-calculating-pythagorean-triples), i.e., [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples).