# Recognizing integer Pythagorean triples geometrically and whether two points constructed on a line are the same

Tags: geometry, polynomials, roots, geometric-construction, pythagorean-triples

This is suggested by the question
[Proof that the sum of the even side and the hypotenuse of a coprime (and positive) Pythagorean triple is a square number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405053/proof-that-the-sum-of-the-even-side-and-the-hypotenuse-of-a-pythagorean-triple-i)
and the fact that I really like
Euclid's original proof
of the Pythagorean theorem
(which only uses the fact that
the area of a triangle
is half the area of
a rectangle with
the same base and altitude).
That proof also proves more,
in that it shows how to divide the
square on the hypotenuse
into two rectangles
each of which has
the same area
as one of the squares on the legs.
It also uses no algebra at all.

My question is:
Is there a geometrical way
to show that
a particular right triangle
has all integer side?

This assumes,
of course,
that we are provided
with a line segment
of length one.

A more basic question
is that of deciding
geometrically
 if
a line segment
has an integer length
(given a unit line segment).

The only geometric construction
I can think of
that might be relevant
 is
that of dividing a segment
into a specified number
of equal segments
(as shown,
for example,
at https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/construct-segment3.html).

An even more basic question
is this:
If two different constructions
each produce a point on a line,
are the two points the same?

This can obviously be handled
algebraically,
since each construction
produces a point
with ordinate
that is a root of
a polynomial of
degree $2^m$
for some $m$.
We then have to decide
if the polynomials
have a common real root.

I do not know if
this question can even be
stated in a
purely geometrical form.

Well,
my question has
wandered enough,
so I'll stop.

Comment: More fundamentally, what geometric construction allows us to tell whether two given segments are congruent or not? Or given points $A,B,C,$ what construction tells us whether $C$ is on the circle with center $A$ that also passes through $B$?